# androidquery AjaxStatus -103 error

Tags: android, ajax, aquery

I'm using AQuery to feed an AutocompleteTextView in my app from a web service. But I got AjaxStatus error -103. What means this status error ?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

public static final int TRANSFORM_ERROR = -103;

It means the http response cannot be transformed to the desired class.

Example:
Using JSONObject as type when the result is an JSONArray.
Using Bitmap as type when the result is in html file.
Using JSONObject as type but the result is a malformed JSON string
etc...

Try hit the url on a browser and see what's being returned. :)